# SpagoBI: MODEL INSTANCE IS NULL, CHECK model_node_instance IN DOCUMENT TEMPLATE.!

Tags: spagobi, kpi

What you read in the title is literally the error I see in the log when I try to execute a KPI document.

I followed the instructions available here: 
http://wiki.spagobi.org/xwiki/bin/view/spagobi_server/KPI+Document+Definition

Here's the full trace of the error:

```
[http-bio-8080-exec-4] 17 Feb 2016 11:19:02,177 ERROR it.eng.spagobi.engines.kpi.SpagoBIKpiInternalEngine.execute:362 - MODEL INSTANCE IS NULL, CHECK model_node_instance IN DOCUMENT TEMPLATE.!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
[http-bio-8080-exec-4] 17 Feb 2016 11:19:02,177 ERROR it.eng.spagobi.engines.kpi.SpagoBIKpiInternalEngine.execute:468 - Generic Error
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at it.eng.spagobi.engines.kpi.SpagoBIKpiInternalEngine.execute(SpagoBIKpiInternalEngine.java:380)
    at it.eng.spagobi.analiticalmodel.document.service.ExecuteBIObjectModule.execute(ExecuteBIObjectModule.java:1063)
    at it.eng.spagobi.analiticalmodel.document.service.ExecuteBIObjectModule.initNewExecutionHandler(ExecuteBIObjectModule.java:402)
    at it.eng.spagobi.analiticalmodel.document.service.ExecuteBIObjectModule.service(ExecuteBIObjectModule.java:138)
    at it.eng.spago.dispatching.module.DefaultPage.invokeServiceBusiness(DefaultPage.java:352)
    at it.eng.spago.dispatching.module.DefaultPage.nextStep(DefaultPage.java:302)
    at it.eng.spago.dispatching.module.DefaultPage.service(DefaultPage.java:202)
    at it.eng.spago.dispatching.module.ModuleCoordinator.service(ModuleCoordinator.java:102)
    at it.eng.spago.dispatching.httpchannel.AdapterHTTP.service(AdapterHTTP.java:425)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at it.eng.spagobi.utilities.filters.AntiInjectionFilter.doFilter(AntiInjectionFilter.java:33)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at it.eng.spagobi.commons.filters.ProfileFilter.doFilter(ProfileFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at it.eng.spagobi.commons.filters.SpagoBICoreCheckSessionFilter.doFilter(SpagoBICoreCheckSessionFilter.java:82)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at it.eng.spagobi.utilities.filters.EncodingFilter.doFilter(EncodingFilter.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

check the value of the *model_node_attribute* in your the Kpi Document template.

The value of this attribute must be the same of the Label field of your Model Instance.

For example in the [SpagoBI Model Instance Definition sample](http://wiki.spagobi.org/xwiki/bin/view/spagobi_server/Model+Instance+Definition) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jftfm.jpg)
the value is: **d09075030-5476-4bab-8**...

so your xml tag must be like this:

...
*KPI model_node_instance='**d09075030-5476-4bab-8...**' name='Title of the document'>*
...

Bye!